# jQuery error when selecting controls with id which contains empty spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to select some textboxes by their name. While this is working fine for controls which don't have empty spaces in their name, I'm getting this error for controls with empty space in their name:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=1180
> Sparkling Water]
>
> throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

This is the code I'm using to get the textbox value:

```
  var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var currentVal = parseInt($("input[name='" + fieldName + "']").val());
```

be careful to not forget the ' ' in the code.. it should look like

```
// correct
var currentVal = parseInt($("input[name='1180 Sparkling Water']").val());
```

from what you had it was

```
//wrong
var currentVal = parseInt($("input[name=1180 Sparkling Water]").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentVal = parseInt($("input[name='" + fieldName + "']").val());
```

Avoid using spaces.